# bind data dynamically dhtmlx calendar mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar, dhtmlx

I currently using DHTMLX calendar in my application with MVC.
Now i load all events by default as follows :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
            {

                var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this);

                scheduler.LoadData = true;
                scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = true;
                ViewBag.EmpId = new SelectList(_userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary(), "EmpId", "First_Name");

                return View(scheduler);
            }

        /* public ContentResult Data()
                {  
              var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(new TimesheetEventDataContext().Events);
               ViewBag.EmpId = new SelectList(_userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary(), "EmpId", "First_Name");              
              return (ContentResult)data;
            }*/
     public ContentResult Data(int UserId)
            {

                ViewBag.EmpId = new SelectList(_userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary(), "EmpId", "First_Name");


                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(new TimesheetEventDataContext().Events.Where(a => a.CreatedBy == UserId.ToString()));
                    ViewBag.EmpId = new SelectList(_userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary(), "EmpId", "First_Name");
                    return (ContentResult)data;
                }
                else
                {
                    var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(new TimesheetEventDataContext().Events.Where(a => a.CreatedBy == Session["EmpId"].ToString()));
                    ViewBag.EmpId = new SelectList(_userRegisterViewModel.GetEmpPrimary(), "EmpId", "First_Name");
                    return (ContentResult)data;              
                }
            }
```

Now i want to load the data by selection user in dropdownlist. So, i pass the userid to controller to fetch the events created by that particualar user. 
My view page is following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Timesheet Events</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            background-color:#eee;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
                emId = $(this).val();
                window.location.href = "/Calendar/Data?UserId=" + emId;              
            });
      });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:700px;width:900px;margin:0 auto;padding-top:10%;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Select User :
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("EmpId", null, "-- Choose --", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlUsers" })
                </td>
                <td colspan="10">
                    <div id="calendar"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        @Html.Raw(Model.Render())
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when i select user it pass the id to controller but not load the calendar view based on that..
can anyone help me to do this..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your #ddlUsers handler does is navigates browser to Data action, which is not what you need.
Try reloading data using client-side API of dhtmlxScheduler

```
$('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
    var emId = $(this).val();

    scheduler.clearAll();
    scheduler.load("/Calendar/Data?UserId=" + emId;, "json");
});
```

Related docs:

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_clearall.html
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_load.html